# Centering prior distributions on MLE/OLS estimates

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, stan

Andrew Gelman recommends placing weakly-informative $N(0, 1)$ priors on unknown parameters fitted in Stan and often does so in his own models. In Stan, the Normal distribution is parameterized by the mean and the standard deviation (not the variance).

I'm looking to fit a binary logistic GLM with at least 8 predictors. My model will also include interaction terms (though I am not sure how many, and whether they will be two-way, or higher order).

In one of Andrew Gelman's YouTube videos, he mentions that regression coefficients from logistic models are usually between -5 and 5. Thus, placing $N(0, 5)$ (where 5 is the standard deviation) priors on all coefficients seems sensible.

I'm wondering if it would be more logical to instead centre my priors on their MLEs, say from `glm()` in R. To me, this only makes sense in the presence of a large amount of data. When there is uncertainty due to limited data, wider priors should be preferred.

Is this a good strategy? What other recommendations are there?

Comment: Suppose the parameters of a prior depend on the data, e.g., on the MLE. In that case, it's not really a prior...  furthermore, consider a maximum a posteriori estimate where the "prior" is symmetric and unimodal with mode at the MLE; it'll just equal the MLE again, rendering the Bayesian aspect of the estimation procedure irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### That is a bad idea

If you use parameter estimates from your data to form your "prior" then it is not really a genuine prior distribution, since it formed using the data.  This then leads to violation of Bayes' rule in the updating process, and means you are not using a genuine Bayesian model.  Such a method will typically "bias" the inference by "double-counting" the data --- i.e., using it once to form the prior and then again to update from the prior to the posterior.  In particular, use of this method will mean that you are exaggerating your effective sample size by double-counting the data.